# Using a XIB's view as subview and access its textfield property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to use `NameSubView` from `NameSubViewController` as a subview in `MainViewController`. I made that work, but I also want to access the `UITextField` of the subview, something like this:

**MainViewController.m**:

```
#import "NameSubViewController.h"

...

UIViewController *nameController = [[NameSubViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NameSubViewController" bundle:nil];
nameSubView = [nameController view];
[self.view addSubview:nameSubView];

NSString *textFieldString = nameSubView.textField.text;
```

---

But I'm having trouble making it work. This is what I've did to create the subview:

- Made `NameSubViewController` class with XIB for interface
- Made `NameSubView` class for the IB view, set the view to this class Identity Inspector
- Created `@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;` in `NameSubView` and connected to the text field in IB.

---

Then I can load the subview, but I could not access the textField from `MainViewController`. So to get access to it I did **change the Files Owner's class** from `NameSubViewController` to `NameSubView` in Identity Inspector.

Now the `NameSubViewController` is accessed, but no property for the view is found, so the app crashes. I don't know if I'm following the right procedure, can I now create a property for the `NameSubView` in `NameSubViewController`? Or should I follow another procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Return the `NameSubViewController` to the file's owner in identity inspector.
- Add the `NameSubView` to the view in identity inspector.

Then use this code:

```
#import "NameSubViewController.h"
// If view's declaration is located in a separate file then the next line is important
#import "NameSubView.h" 

...

// It is better to declare the view controller as 'NameSubViewController'
NameSubViewController *nameController = [[NameSubViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NameSubViewController" bundle:nil];
// A casting to 'NameSubView' should do the main magic
NameSubView *nameSubView = (NameSubView *)[nameController view];
[self.view addSubview:nameSubView];

// It is better to ensure that the view is of a correct class 
// before using its specific properties
if ([nameSubView isKindOfClass:[NameSubView class]]) {
  // Now it should work 
  // (assuming that you have a property 'textField' in 'NameSubView')
  NSString *textFieldString = nameSubView.textField.text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, working like magic. Saved me from a lot of experimenting and confusion.

Answer (score 1):

First, change file's owner back to `NameSubViewController`. Move the textfield IBOutlet declaration to NameSubViewController, and make sure everything is connected properly in the nib. Finally, declare your `nameController` variable to be of type `NameSubViewController` and not UIViewController. You should then be able to get the textfield with `nameController.textField`